# Search after multiple parameters, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and trying to create a search function that allows the user to serach multiple parameters at the same time; from, and to. Something to keep in mind is that there will probably be even more parameters later on in the development. I've got it to work when searching for one of the fields, but not more than that.

Search view:

```
<%= form_tag(journeys_path, :method => "get", from: "search-form") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_from, params[:search_from], placeholder: "Search from", :class => 'input' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_to, params[:search_to], placeholder: "Search to", :class => 'input' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => 'submit' %>
  <% end %>
```

Method:

```
class Journey < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search_from)
    self.where("from_place LIKE ?", "%#{search_from}%")
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class JourneysController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @journeys = Journey.all
      if params[:search_from]
        @journeys = Journey.search(params[:search_from])
      else
        @journeys = Journey.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def search
    @journeys = Journey.search(params[:search_from])
  end
end
```

I've tried some gems and all kind of solutions that I've found in other questions, but I'm just not good enough at RoR yet to succesfully apply them correctly without help. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want to use any gem then check Rails Way of doing multiple search http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model:

```
class Journey < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search_from, search_to)
    self.where("from_place LIKE ? and to_place LIKE ?", "%#{search_from}%", "%#{search_to}%")
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class JourneysController < ApplicationController

  def index
      if params[:search_from] and params[:search_to]
        @journeys = search
      else
        @journeys = Journey.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def search
    @journeys = Journey.search(params[:search_from], params[:search_to])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to incapsulate your search form as a separate Ruby class. Using [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) here helps to get type coercion for free.

```
class SearchForm
  include Virtus.model # Our virtus module
  include ActiveModel::Model # To get ActiveRecord-like behaviour for free.

  attribute :from, String
  attribute :to, String

  # Just to check if any search param present, 
  # you could substitute this with validations and just call valid?
  def present?
    attributes.values.any?{|value| value.present?}
  end
```

```

In Rails 3 IIRC you also have to include ActiveModel::Validations to be able to validate your form input if needed.
Now, let's see how to refactor controller. We instantiate form object from params and pass that to the model query method to fetch records needed. I also moved ordering out of if clause and used symbol ordering param - cleaner IMO.

```
def index
  @search_form = SearchForm.new(search_params)
  if @search_form.valid? && @search_form.present?
    @journeys = Journey.search(@search_form)
  else
    @journeys = Journey.all
  end
  @journeys = @journeys.order(created_at: :desc)
end

def search
  @journeys = Journey.search(SearchForm.new(search_params)
end

private
def search_params
  params.require(:search_form).permit(:from, :to)
end
```

Now to the view: form_for will work perfectly with our form object, as will simple_form_for

```
<%= form_for @search_form, url: journeys_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :from, placeholder: "Search from", class: 'input' %>
  <%= f.text_field :to, placeholder: "Search to", class: 'input' %>
  <%= f.submit "Search", class: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

View looks now much shorter and cleaner. Incapsulating params in object makes working with search params muuuuch easier.

Model:

```
class Journey < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search_form)
    if search_form.kind_of?(SearchForm)
      journeys = all # I'm calling Journey.all here to build ActiveRecord::Relation object
      if search_form.from.present?
        journeys = journeys.where("from_place LIKE ?", "%#{search_form.from}%")
      end
      if search_form.to.present?
        journeys = journeys.where("to_place LIKE ?", "%#{search_form.to}%")
      end
    else
      raise ArgumentError, 'You should pass SearchForm instance to Journey.search method'
    end
  end
end
```

Notice how I build ActiveRecord::Relation object by calling `Journeys.all` and applying each search param if present. Chaining `where` like that would put `AND` in between automatically, if you need `OR` Rails 4 has it: `Journey.or(condition)`.
Pros of this approach:

1. You are using Plain Old Ruby Classes, almost no magic here, and it works like usual Rails model in many ways. Putting search params in the object makes it a lot easier to refactor code. Virtus is the only dependency, sans Rails itself of course, and it's more for convenience and to avoid writing boring boiler-plate code.
2. You can easily validate input if needed (If you really want to be strict about input and show user validation error instead of silently executing stupid query with contradicting conditions and returning no results).

Comment: Great answer! I tried the short solutions posted by the two guys above, but will absolutely see if I can make my code look better with your ideas, thank you!

Comment: What is left out of the scope of my answer is pagination. It's pretty important  to always limit your queries with paging in production - if user don't fill in form fields you'll end with Journey.all. Now imagine there are 100000 records in the table, server will eat some 1gb of memory serving just this one request. I recomend [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) for paging, as it's pretty straightforward and flexible about html-markup it generates.